# org.json JAR provisioning

Tags: json, jar

I was wondering why www.json.org/anyone else doesn't provide an official JAR package of org.json for download? All queries I find of people asking where they can download the JAR results in replies to the page which just lists the source files.

It seems a bit cumbersome to expect everybody to download each source file and prepare the JAR file themselves.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you considered using Maven?  for instance, if you wanted a JAR to pars JSON you could just include...

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.6

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.6</version>
</dependency>
```

in a pom.xml, this will give you the jar for JSON.

Or better yet, use the org.json one...

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Just a quick warning... the version of org.json that's available in the maven repo is much older that the current release on github https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java.  I had some issues with the maven release that I assume were bugs that were fixed because using the latest release directly solved the issues for me.

Comment: The crappy solution here is to go to Crockford's JSON java implementation, forking it, and creating a jar out of it. I did this, and it's a maven project as well, so you can install it into your repo, or, just create a jar w/ it. https://github.com/anatolyg/JSON-java

Comment: Version 20131018 is also in the mvn repository for those who wonder.

Comment: The Maven repo is now up to date as of 12 Feb 2016. New releases are uploaded about every 3 months or as needed: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded a jar from here:
http://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/detail?name=org.json-20120521.jar&can=2&q=

Answer (score 1):

The implementation from json.org by Douglas Crockford is nōn-free. Luckily, a Free almost drop-in replacement exists (apparently, Google’s code packaged by someone else for Maven Central):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
</dependency>
```

Add this to `pom.xml` instead of using the json.org one. We had to do only one minor change to our code for this: the vaadin one can throw `JSONException` in more places, so we had to either catch them or pass them through to the callers (extend the throws declaration).

Comment: I have also packaged this onto Maven and made a number of changes to make it easier to port to. Notably, JSONException is now unchecked. See https://github.com/tdunning/open-json (also available via maven)

Answer (score 1):

Beware that the json.org software has a non-open source license. This causes downstream problems in many cases.

The issue is that the license is essentially the MIT license, but it adds a line that says that the software should only be used for good, not evil. This sounds fine, but if you have to get a corporate lawyer to sign off it gets nasty because there is no consensus legal definition of "evil". If you use json.org's library, you can't put your software into Debian, for instance. Your software likewise can't be a dependency for any Apache project.

To help with this, I have adapted and packaged the android clean-room rewrite of the json.org library. The source is on github and is Apache licensed. See https://github.com/tdunning/open-json. To use this, add something like this to your pom (or equivalent):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.tdunning/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tdunning</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Ping me with pull requests or issues on github or however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Using the com.tdunnning package can lead to dependency conflicts, especially if you make your project available to others as a library.  The implementation does not have 100% compatibility with org.json

That package(com.tdunning) has been forked to https://github.com/openjson/openjson with the package renamed to com.github.openjson instead of org.json to prevent conflicts.

The maven dependency:

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.github.openjson</groupId>
>     <artifactId>openjson</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0.10</version>
> </dependency>
> ```